# how to make standard ssh port a stealth port?

Tags: ssh, firewall, tcpip, server-settings, stealth

I'm running a personal ssh server on a nonstandard port. If someone tries to log into my ssh server thru the standard port 22, it seems that the server sends "Connection refused" message.

```
$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

How can I make it so that it doesn't send such message and it behaves like it's not running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server is not sending anything, it's the ***client*** telling you the server refused the connection. That's the expected behaviour if a TCP port is **closed** when you try to connect.

If you want your system to silently drop packets without sending a "this port is closed" TCP answer (a so-called *stealth* port), you need to use a firewall on the system and/or in between it and the client.

Comment: This is not correct! The server network stack is sending packets. When a client program sends a TCP SYN packet to request a connection, a reply packet with the ACK and RST flags set, according to examination of captured packets, is classified as a connection refused error. No server is listening on the port, and the port is closed as you said correctly.

Comment: I was meaning that "connection refused" message was not sent by the server, as the original poster thought; it was the client application stating that the server had refused the connection. I think those three downvotes were a bit too much.

Answer (score 7):

You've already done it -- the connection refused response is sent by the operating system when an attempt is made to connect to a port which doesn't have anything listening on it.

Answer (score 3):

What you see is most likely your client's reaction to an [ICMP port-unreachable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Destination_Unreachable)  sent by the server upon receiving the first TCP SYN-packet for a port that does not accept connections. This is correct behavior and allows the client to quickly tell you so.

If you actually mean stealth as in "this host is non-existing, dead or offline and doesn't send anything at all", configure your firewall to drop (as opposed to reject) any packets to this port. Assuming netfilter/iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

This leads to the client hanging for a while as it cannot decide if a response is in transit or non-existant.

Note: This will actually kill all connections instantly, including the running ones. Molly switch alert!

Answer (score 3):

The server network stack is sending packets in response to the client TCP connect attempt.

When a client program sends a TCP **SYN** packet to request a connection, a reply packet with the **ACK and RST flags set**, according to examination of captured packets, is classified as a **connection refused error**. No service is listening on the port, and the port is closed.

- if you want a "stealth" port my suggestion is to do nothing, as this is the expected behavior of a closed port with no service behind.
- if you would DROP packets on this port you will have a "filtered" port at nmap scan, making an attacker to think that a service is listening and a firewall is denying access to him
- furthermore DROP is not a "*polite* target", as it makes the net obscure to clients. DROP should be used with care.
- if you really want a port to be a nice attacker enemy you could be interested in the [tarpit iptables module](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/patch-o-matic/pom-external.html#pom-external-TARPIT)
- if you want to disorient your attacker you can join the REJECT target and play with exotics combination of [ICMP error codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP%5FDestination%5FUnreachable) and *--reject-type*:

> REJECT
>       --reject-with type
>       The type given can be
>             icmp-net-unreachable
>             icmp-host-unreachable
>             icmp-port-unreachable
>             icmp-proto-unreachable
>             icmp-net-prohibited
>             icmp-host-prohibited or
>             icmp-admin-prohibited

Answer (score 1):

You can completely stealth your `ssh` port with `fwknop` in conjunction with setting a default deny policy in `iptables` to silently drop packets. All `nmap` will see are the public services.

> *With [fwknop](http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/) deployed, anyone using nmap to look for SSHD can't even tell that it is listening - it makes no difference if they want to run
>   a password cracker against SSHD or even if they have a 0-day exploit.*

See my [guide for fwknop](https://it-offshore.co.uk/security/53-stealth-your-ssh-port-ssh-into-lxc-containers) & the accompanying pages for secure `ssh` ciphers.